# I can't grab data from opened tab

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code to grab the content of the page which I opened by javascript but my code doesn't work .
could you tell me whats wrong with my code and it would be better if you introduce me a better way to grab a page content, like what I'm trying to do.

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
x = myWindow.document.innerHTML;
alert(x);
```

Comment: FWIW, I would advise using`console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: Best way to debug such issues is to check the developer tools on your browser. You can put a breakpoint at a specific line and see whats the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems there:

1. You're trying to get the information before it's available (the `window.open` call returns immediately, before the page is actually loaded).
2. You can't access information from other *origins* because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), unless the other site specifically allows you to.

That second issue pretty much makes what you're trying to do impossible to do purely client-side without help from the other site. Instead, you'd have to have a server that requests the information from the other site, and then sends it to your page. (It doesn't necessarily have to be *your* server; it's possible to [use YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax) and there are probably other similar services out there.)